# is it possible to get the MAX of a column and update it with a single query?

Tags: sql, sql-update, max

I have a scenario were i need to find the maximum value of the column and then to update a row by increment one with the maximum value found. Can it be done this way?

```
update student SET stud_rank=MAX(stud_rank)+1 where stud_id=6
```

Comment: So, all rows where `stud_id` is equal to 6 should become equal to the previous maximum + 1?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever yes it should

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
update student set
    stud_rank = (select max(stud_rank) from student) + 1
where stud_id=6
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one -

```
UPDATE student
SET stud_rank = (SELECT MAX(stud_rank) + 1 FROM student)
WHERE stud_id = 6
```

Answer (score 0):

if you need the MAX value for `stud_id = 6` you can do as this

```
update student 
SET stud_rank=MAX(MaxRank)+1 
FROM student s 
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT MAX(stud_rank) AS MaxRank, stud_id
    FROM  students
) topRank ON s.stud_id = topRank.stud_id 
WHERE s.stud_id=6
```

Answer (score 0):

if you execute your above query than you will get below error in sqlserver :-

> An aggregate may not appear in the set list of an UPDATE statement.

You have to change your query as :-

```
update student SET stud_rank=(select MAX(stud_rank)+1 from student) where stud_id=6
```